# Dart how to arrange a nested Map based on a certain common value?

Tags: dart, dictionary

Hi all I am trying to sort this Map<int, dynamic> from highest to lowest based on the "clicks" value. Here is my map and what i would like the sorted Map to look like. Thank you for your time with this question.

```
Map<int, dynamic> myMap = {
    0: {"clicks": 12, "timeStamp": "2023-08-11 11:40:36.783"},
    1: {"clicks": 1, "timeStamp": "2023-08-12 10:47:36.783"},
    2: {"clicks": 29, "timeStamp": "2023-08-13 10:47:36.783"},
    3: {"clicks": 5, "timeStamp": "2023-08-01 10:47:36.783"},
    4: {"clicks": 90, "timeStamp": "2023-08-19 10:47:36.783"},
  };
    myMapArranged = {
    4: {"clicks": 90, "timeStamp": "2023-08-19 10:47:36.783"},
    2: {"clicks": 29, "timeStamp": "2023-08-13 10:47:36.783"},
    0: {"clicks": 12, "timeStamp": "2023-08-11 11:40:36.783"},
    3: {"clicks": 5, "timeStamp": "2023-08-01 10:47:36.783"},
    1: {"clicks": 1, "timeStamp": "2023-08-12 10:47:36.783"},
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you want a map rather than a list? You're only using keys 0 - 4 and order matters to you.

Comment: Yeah if you don't want the keys, you can make a list of Data mode having clicks and timeStamp, and sorting on that would be much easier. For now i'm putting answer for your question.

Comment: Hi yes, keys themselves are linked to another Map. And this map will be growable over time, so every time it gets updated the map will be yet again sorted... if that makes sense??

Comment: @RishV got it, so you want a sorted map sorted by clicks? Will the `clicks` values be unique, or does it need to be a multimap?

Comment: That is correct. Each Map value will all be unique in terms of all having a clicks value and timestamp just that clicks will change when doing certain things within the app. @pixel has created a solution for me that works perfectly :)  Thank you for your time Luatic, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to sort the Map with the number of clicks:

```
  List<int> sortedKeys = myMap.keys.toList()
    ..sort((a, b) => myMap[b]["clicks"].compareTo(myMap[a]["clicks"]));
  print(sortedKeys);

  Map<int, dynamic> myMapArranged = {for (int i in sortedKeys) i: myMap[i]};
  print(myMapArranged);
```

the sortedKeys will have the sorted keys as per the clicks, and the MyMapArranged will have the final sorted map.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you need to keep this map sorted by clicks updated, you want a sorted map to do this efficiently. In Dart this is implemented by the [`SplayTreeMap`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.7/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap-class.html). You'll have to  `import 'dart:collection';` for this.

I will assume that your "clicks" aren't unique, so each value will need to be a list of values (timestamps in this case).

```dart
final eventsByClicks = SplayTreeMap<int, List<DateTime>>((a, b) => b.compareTo(a));
put(int clicks, DateTime timestamp) {
    final list = eventsByClicks[clicks] ?? [];
    list.add(timestamp);
    eventsByClicks[clicks] = list;
}
```

To insert your example data:

```dart
put(12, DateTime.parse("2023-08-11 11:40:36.783"));
put(1, DateTime.parse("2023-08-12 10:47:36.783"));
put(29, DateTime.parse("2023-08-13 10:47:36.783"));
put(5, DateTime.parse("2023-08-01 10:47:36.783"));
put(90, DateTime.parse("2023-08-19 10:47:36.783"));
```

Then you can iterate inorder as follows:

```dart
for (final entry in eventsByClicks.entries) {
    for (final timestamp in entry.value)
        print("${entry.key} $timestamp");
}
```

The result is as wanted:

```
90 2023-08-19 10:47:36.783
29 2023-08-13 10:47:36.783
12 2023-08-11 11:40:36.783
5 2023-08-01 10:47:36.783
1 2023-08-12 10:47:36.783
```